# localStorage in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Please help to resolve my problem;

I have a React Component. And I have SetInterval in one of function.

I want: after reload page component should continue work (setInterval is running and all states is updating)

How to do it with localStorage?

I tried to save all states lo ls, but setInterval stoped work and it is not what I need.

My code is bellow

```js
class StopWatch extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   startTime: null,
   endTime: null,
   isRunning: null,
   currentTime: 0,
   
  }
 }


 formatingTime = (time) => {
  const formattedTime = new Date(time);
  let hours = formattedTime.getUTCHours().toString();
  let minutes = formattedTime.getMinutes().toString();
  let seconds = formattedTime.getSeconds().toString();

  if (hours.length < 2) { hours = `0${hours}`; }

     if (minutes.length < 2) { minutes = `0${minutes}`; }

     if (seconds.length < 2) { seconds = `0${seconds}`; }

     return (`${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`)


 }

 


 updateStopWatch = () => {
  let updatedTime = this.state.currentTime + 1000

  console.log(updatedTime)

  this.setState({
   currentTime: updatedTime
  })
 }



 startStopWatch = () => {

  let startTime = Date.now();



  this.setState({
   startTime: startTime,
   currentTime: 0,
   isRunning: true,
   runClock: setInterval(this.updateStopWatch, 1000)

  })
 }

 stopStopWatch = () => {
  let endTime = Date.now();

  this.setState({
   endTime: endTime,
   isRunning: false,
  })

  clearInterval(this.state.runClock)

 }




 render = () => {

  // console.log(this.state.isRunning)

  return (

   <div>
    <h1>{this.formatingTime(this.state.currentTime)}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.startStopWatch}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={this.stopStopWatch}>Stop</button>
   </div>

  )
 }
}



ReactDOM.render(<StopWatch />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: I edited your snipped. It was not working before because the root div and react was missing.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-interval This is the thing i think will work for you